# How do I fetch youtube title and description from given url using python code?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How do I fetch youtube title and description from python code from the given url. Is it necessory to use youtube API for it? I am writing a program which need to find generate title and description from given url

Comment: Where exactly is the information originally? You can easily use some sort of HTML parser or regular expression depending on the problem, but it's hard to figure out what that is with the question. Are you browsing the site and want to download all descriptions and titles? Do you want to put in a URL of a video and grab that?

Answer (score 7):

It is not *necessary*, but it is probably significantly quicker and easier than writing your own.

For more information, see https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python

After installing the `gdata` module, try

```
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()

# authorize - you need to sign up for your own access key, or be rate-limited
# yt_service.developer_key = 'ABCxyz123...'
# yt_service.client_id = 'My-Client_id'

def PrintEntryDetails(entry):
    print 'Video title: %s' % entry.media.title.text
    print 'Video published on: %s ' % entry.published.text
    print 'Video description: %s' % entry.media.description.text
    print 'Video category: %s' % entry.media.category[0].text
    print 'Video tags: %s' % entry.media.keywords.text
    print 'Video watch page: %s' % entry.media.player.url
    print 'Video flash player URL: %s' % entry.GetSwfUrl()
    print 'Video duration: %s' % entry.media.duration.seconds

for entry in yt_service.GetTopRatedVideoFeed().entry:
    PrintEntryDetails(entry)
```

Answer (score 6):

Both answers no longer work the first because the V2 API is no longer available the other one because the URL resource is no longer available.

This is a V3 code that is working:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

DEVELOPER_KEY = 'your api key goes here'
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

ids = '5rC0qpLGciU,LgbuxTfJFr0'
results = youtube.videos().list(id=ids, part='snippet').execute()
for result in results.get('items', []):
    print result['id']
    print result['snippet']['description']
    print result['snippet']['title']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, after I created an API key using the google developers console.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to write one by yourself without being tracked by YouTube with your developer key, you can simply send a request to:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/#{video_id}
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/#{video_id}?alt=json
```

Such as: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/fcz_DYms4N4.
It can return XML, JSON, or JSONP depending on your need.

Comment: Your link returns 404.

Comment: Looks like Google shut down unauthenticated API access.