# XPath get full text of Youtube Video description in Python?

Tags: python, xpath, youtube, lxml

I am trying to get the text of the description of a given Youtube video using Xpath and lxml, however it is only returning the first few sentences of the description then "...". So its cutting it short, im wondering if there is something wrong with my xpath or if its always like that? I haven't seen any related threads to this yet.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import urllib3

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Baur2Ypgd60"

page=requests.get(url)     

tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
s=tree.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content')
print(s)
```

This only prints: ["The Best of 2020  This year had its challenges—but you can't stop this train. A global #GoProFamily met adversity with creativity, resilience, + unity. You..."],

rather than the full text of the description: ["The Best of 2020  This year had its challenges—but you can't stop this train. A global #GoProFamily met adversity with creativity, resilience, + unity. You never lost sight of your passions, even if it meant practicing them from your living rooms. We're grateful, inspired, + hungry for the future."]

This seems like it would be an easy fix but im not too familar with XPath stuff and couldnt find anything about this anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: If the XPath is correct, it could be another problem, youtube loads the page not full at once. Maybe the title is load afterward via javascript. To look if this is the problem, try to write the page via requests into a file. Then you can check by hand if the title loaded, if yes this is an XPath problem if not you have to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: @kabr8 it is an XPath issue because I tried it as well with selenium previously and the result was the same.

Comment: strange because when I do it says `<meta name="description" content="The Best of 2020  This year had its challenges—but you can&#39;t stop this train. A global #GoProFamily met adversity with creativity, resilience, + unity. You...">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the meta description tag only contains

`The Best of 2020  This year had its challenges—but you can&#39;t stop this train. A global #GoProFamily met adversity with creativity, resilience, + unity. You...`

but what you want to get is this `div`:

```html
<div id="description" slot="content" class="style-scope ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer"></div>
```

In this there is the hole video discription.

But the smartes way to get the description is to use the [Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321447/11419075).